# Multiple lists input to a file

Tags: python

I have 4 lists with equal length.
like:

```
List1: x1,x2,x3,x4...
List2: y1,y2,y3,y4...
List3: z1,z2,z3,z4,...
list4: a1,a2,a3,a4,....
```

I want to read them and write to a file as:

x1,y1,z1,a1....

for that :

```
with open('do.txt','a+') as writefile:
   for i in iter(List1):
      writefile.write(i)
```

how can we write all the in the file at the same time.

Comment: Did you try `zip`?

Comment: `open('do.txt','a+').write('\n'.join(','.join(t) for t in zip(list1,list2,list3,list4)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zip` should solve your problem

```
with open('do.txt','a+') as writefile:
    for a,b,c,d in zip(list1,list2,list3,list4):
        writefile.write("{},{},{},{}\n".format(a,b,c,d))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
with open('do.txt','a+') as writefile:  
    writefile.write('\n'.join(','.join(t for t in zip(list1,list2,list3,list4))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun this is one line solution :)

```
[open('writing_file.txt', 'a+').write("{},{},{},{}\n".format(a,b,c,d)) for a,b,c,d in zip(list1,list2,list3,list4)]
```

Above list comprehension is same as:

```
with open('writing_file.txt','a+') as file_1:
    for a,b,c,d in zip(list1,list2,list3,list4):
        file_1.write("{},{},{},{}\n".format(a,b,c,d))
```